# How to set response header for digital asset in AEM CQ6.1?

Tags: java, aem, sling

I have a request that if a user directly accesses a .pdf asset(for example, http://localhost:4505/content/dam/company/us/en/962059.pdf)  from AEM CQ 6.1, I need to send a custom http respone header. This is what I wrote. This is only works if I open a .html page. But it doesn't work if I open a .pdf in browser. So what did I do wrong?

Thanks

```
package com.mycompany.wcm.filter;


import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.*;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.sling.SlingFilter;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.sling.SlingFilterScope;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.*;
import org.apache.sling.api.scripting.SlingBindings;
import org.apache.sling.api.scripting.SlingScriptHelper;
import org.apache.sling.runmode.RunMode;
import org.osgi.service.cm.Configuration;
import org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@SlingFilter(
        label = "Sample Filter",
        description = "Sample Description",
        metatype = true,
        generateComponent = true, // True if you want to leverage activate/deactivate
        generateService = true,
        order = -501, // The smaller the number, the earlier in the Filter chain (can go negative);
        scope = SlingFilterScope.REQUEST)
@Properties({
        @Property(
                label = "Vendor",
                name = "service.vendor",
                value = "SampleVendor",
                propertyPrivate = true
        )
})
public class AssetFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = (SlingHttpServletRequest) request;
        final SlingHttpServletResponse slingResponse = (SlingHttpServletResponse) response;
        slingResponse.setHeader("myheader1","no-cache");
        slingResponse.setHeader("myheader2","no-store");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

---

Just a update, initialy I thought the problem only happens to .pdf file, but this also happens to image file. So I created a regular JSP web application, and this code is working for regular web app.  Is there something funny on AEM side?

Comment: Is there a reason you would prefer not to set your caching headers from your Dispatcher / Apache Web Server?

Comment: nateyolles, Actually, I am also looking for alernative ways to achieve this. My problem is the custom headers are sent based on JCR node property. For example, if node property is marked "sent custom header", then it sends the response header. I am not sure if Dispatcher or Web server could achieve this?